# Can´t save $_POST from <form> into .html

Tags: php, html, forms, post, fwrite

I try to save `$_POST` from a `<form>` into a .txt file. If i click on the submit button, my code will save only the `$date` variable, and not `$date` & `$hour`.

This is my form in "form.php"

```
<form method="post" action="save.php" id="formID">
 <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" id="nameFieldID">
  <input type="text" name="Hour" placeholder="Hour" id="hourFieldID">
   <input type="submit" name="" value="" id="submitButton">
    </form>
```

This is the code in my "save.php"

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$date = date("d.M Y");
$time = date("H:i:s");
$name = $_POST["Name"];
$hour = $_POST["Hour"];

$file = "nameAndHour.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "a");
$details = fread($handle, filesize($file));

fclose($handle);

$handle = fopen("nameAndHour.txt", "a");
fwrite($handle, $detail);
fwrite($handle, $date, "\t");
fwrite($handle, $time, "\t");
fwrite($handle, $name, "\t");
fwrite($handle, $hour);
fclose($handle);

include('form.php');
?>
```

Could anybody help me, to get the `$_POST` variables in the my .txt file? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)`, to see what arrived at the server? You're just assuming your form is working correctly.

Comment: Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /homepages/... And for all five `fwrite`: Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in /homepages/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure the (text) file exists before attempting to write to it and has proper permissions to write to, otherwise you will receive the following warning:

> Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0

- *Sidenote:* Consult my footnotes.

You then need to replace all commas for `, "\t"` with dots `. "\t"`.

That is why you're getting the following warning(s):

> Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given

**Rewrite:**

```
<?php 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$date = date("d.M Y");
$time = date("H:i:s");
$name = $_POST["Name"];
$hour = $_POST["Hour"];

$file = "nameAndHour.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "a");
$detail = fread($handle, filesize($file));

fclose($handle);

$handle = fopen("nameAndHour.txt", "a");
fwrite($handle, $detail);
fwrite($handle, $date . "\t");
fwrite($handle, $time . "\t");
fwrite($handle, $name . "\t");
fwrite($handle, $hour);

fclose($handle);

include('form.php');
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

You could also check to see if the file exists, using `file_exists()` with a conditional statement.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Example:

```
if (file_exists("nameAndHour.txt")) {
// execute code
...
}

else{
   echo "File does not exist.";
}
```

---

Another thing. About your last line:

```
fwrite($handle, $hour);
```

You should add a `"\n"` for it so that there is a carriage return inserted after the last entry, otherwise your file will be written in one long line.

```
fwrite($handle, $hour . "\n");
```

---

> *"Is there also a way to put the details in a table? Can I use HTML?"*

**Edit:** (a quick HTML table example)

To write data in an HTML table, you can use something like this:

```
$table1 = "<table>";
$table2 = "</table>";

$tr1 = "<tr>";
$tr2 = "</tr>";

$td1 = "<td>";
$td2 = "</td>";

fwrite($handle, $table1 . "\n");

fwrite($handle, $tr1 . "\n");
fwrite($handle, $td1 . "\n");

fwrite($handle, $date . "\t");
fwrite($handle, $time . "\t");
fwrite($handle, $name . "\t");
fwrite($handle, $hour . "\n");

fwrite($handle, $tr2 . "\n");
fwrite($handle, $td2 . "\n");

fwrite($handle, $table2 . "\n");
```

will write out, and as an example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
28.May 2015 21:41:35    data1a  data1b
</tr>
</td>
</table>
```

- But you will need to experiment with that. I cannot elaborate anymore on this, since it was not part of the original question.

Comment: Trank you so much! I had no permission! Now it works.

Comment: Yes, i did it all ready. Is there also a way to put the details in a table? Can I use HTML?

Comment: @MaximilianFixl You're quite welcome. As for HTML, that is possible but you may have to post another question if you have a hard time to do that. I shouldn't see why you couldn't write HTML, just as long as it's valid syntax.

Comment: @MaximilianFixl I've posted an example for you. Reload my answer and look under **Edit: (a quick HTML table example)**. Unfortunately, I won't be able to offer anymore help on this, since it was not part of the original question. I'm sure you'll be able to continue on with that example.

Comment: Thanks! I got it! I changed the .txt in .html and now I'm on a good way! Once again: Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just made a syntax error.

Change

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ""de_DE.utf8");
```

To

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8");
```

Comment: Thank you for you'r attention, but in my local file is no syntax error. It was just in my question here.

Answer (score 0):

syntx error at line 2 of save.php. remove additional " and it is better to have some rest and relax before coding so you may avoid these mistakes

use

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.utf8");
```

instead of

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ""de_DE.utf8");
```